# Browser not saving cookies in MERN stack application

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express

i am currently following a youtube tutorial on a mern stack project and can't get my cookies to save in the browser after login . I don't know how to solve this issue , can someone please help ?

here's the code

This is my first project so I'm having trouble trying to solve it . I followed the steps in the youtube tutorial and the guy doesn't seem to have any problem with this part , what am i doing wrong ? sorry if the format is wrong , this is my first time asking question in stack overflow as well , hope someone can help

```
//create token and save to cookies
const sendToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
  const token = user.getJwtToken();

  //options for cookes
  const options = {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
    sameSite: "none",
    httpOnly: true,
  };

  res.status(statusCode).cookie("token", token, options).json({
    success: true,
    user,
    token,
  });
};

module.exports = sendToken;
 

// for authentication 

const ErrorHandler = require("../utils/ErrorHandler");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const catchAsyncErrors = require("./catchAsyncError");
const User = require ("../model/user");

exports.isAuthenticated = catchAsyncErrors(async(req,res,next)=> {
    const {token} = req.cookies;

    if(!token){
        return next (new ErrorHandler("Please Login to continue",401));
     }

    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY);

    req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id);

    next();
});


//user controller

const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const { upload } = require("../multer");
const User = require("../model/user");
const ErrorHandler = require("../utils/ErrorHandler");
const catchAsyncErrors = require("../middleware/catchAsyncError");
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require("fs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const sendMail = require("../utils/sendMail");
const sendToken = require("../utils/jwtToken");
const user = require("../model/user");
const {isAuthenticated} = require("../middleware/auth");

router.post("/create-user", upload.single("file"), async (req, res, next) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;
  const userEmail = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (userEmail) {
    //if user already exist make sure files uploaded into the form is also deleted
    const filename = req.file.filename;
    const filePath = `uploads/${filename}`;
    fs.unlink(filePath, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Error deleting file" });
      }
    });

    return next(new ErrorHandler("User already exists", 400));
  }

  const filename = req.file.filename; //request the name of the file uploaded
  const fileUrl = path.join(filename); //create the file url to store in db

  const user = {
    name: name,
    email: email,
    password: password,
    avatar: fileUrl,
  };

  const activationToken = createActivationToken(user);
  const activationUrl = `http://localhost:3000/activation/${activationToken}`;

  try {
    await sendMail({
      email: user.email,
      subject: "Activate your account",
      message: `Hello ${user.name}, please click on the link to activate your account: ${activationUrl}`,
    });
    res.status(201).json({
      success: true,
      message: `please check your email:- ${user.email} to activate your account!`,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 500));
  }
});

//create activation token
const createActivationToken = (user) => {
  return jwt.sign(user, process.env.ACTIVATION_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: "5m",
  });
};

//activate user
router.post(
  "/activation",
  catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const { activation_token } = req.body;
      const newUser = jwt.verify(
        activation_token,
        process.env.ACTIVATION_SECRET
      ); //check if token is valid

      if (!newUser) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler("Invalid token", 400)); //if token not valid , return error
      }

      const { name, email, password, avatar } = newUser;

      let user = await User.findOne({ email }); //check if already exist user with that email

      if (user) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler("User already existed", 400));
      }

      user = await User.create({
        name,
        email,
        avatar,
        password,
      });

      sendToken(user, 201, res);
    } catch (error) {
      return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 500));
    }
  })
);

//login user
router.post(
  "/login-user",
  catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const { email, password } = req.body;

      if (!email || !password) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler("Please provide the all fields!", 400));
      }

      const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select("+password");

      if (!user) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler("User doesn't exists!", 400));
      }

      const isPasswordValid = await user.comparePassword(password);

      if (!isPasswordValid) {
        return next(
          new ErrorHandler("Please provide the correct information", 400)
        );
      }

      sendToken(user, 201, res);
    } catch (error) {
      return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 500));
    }
  })
);

//load user
router.get(
  "/getuser",
  isAuthenticated,
  catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);

      if (!user) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler("User doesn't exists!", 400));
      }

      res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        user,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 500));
    }
  })
);

module.exports = router;


// the handle submit in user login 
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    await axios
    .post(
      `${server}/user/login-user`,
      {
        email,
        password,
      },
      { withCredentials: true }
    )
    .then((res) => {
      toast.success("Login Success!");
      navigate("/");
      window.location.reload(true); 
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      toast.error(err.response.data.message);
    });

  };

//In the app.js 
const express = require("express");
const ErrorHandler = require("./middleware/error");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
  })
); //so we can call api from anywhere in the world after deployed
app.use("/", express.static("uploads")); //so we can access the uploads folder globally
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: "50mb" }));

//config
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "PRODUCTION") {
  require("dotenv").config({
    path: "backend/config/.env",
  });
}

const user = require("./controller/user");

app.use("/api/v2/user", user);

//For error handling
app.use(ErrorHandler);

module.exports = app;
```